# How do i create production build for angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created angular2 quickstart demo on my local machine.I tried to find solution for generating build for angular 2 application. I got some hint on webpack etc..but i didnt get proper idea..so anyone can provide me solution on this it would really help me.

Comment: I want to run my angular 2 application on apache(xampp).

Comment: I use Angular-CLI. The latest update has Webpack integrated: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Answer (score 0):

you can look into this seed project.
https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed

its quite an overkill for your question, but you will get an idea how to create production and development builds.

tl;dr: use many gulp plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You can use global constantst with `DefinePlugin`.

### DefinePlugin

The DefinePlugin allows you to create global constants which can be configured at compile time. This can be very useful for allowing different behaviour between development builds and release builds. For example, you might use a global constant to determine whether logging takes place; perhaps you perform logging in your development build but not in the release build. That’s the sort of scenario the DefinePlugin facilates.

### Example

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    PRODUCTION: JSON.stringify(true)
})
if (PRODUCTION)
    //here you can have your conditional objects which you want to build or not
```

there are some other plugins as well just. I use to split webpack config into common, dev and prod.
[Here is a simple seed i created](https://github.com/blinfo/angular2-webpack-seed/tree/master/config) take a look to see how i used different config for different environment.

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as a command 'ng build --prod' in your app root folder in case if you are using recommended angular cli for build process.